# Expression confusion to filter parameter selection

Tags: sql, reporting-services, expression

Could any one please help to fix this expression.
Under the Filter tab i am trying to do values selection from multi-value parameter.
where i have to add value 'C160' if left of column value is 'C15' and in the same manner,
i have to ignore value 'C160' if the column value is 'C16'.

--

### My expression is, IIF(COND,TRUE,FALSE)

```
  =IIF(Parameters!Site.Value="C15",Parameters!Site.Value AND "C160",(IIF(Parameters!Site.Value="C16",Parameters!Site.Value AND NOT "C160",Parameters!Site.Value)))
```

Error: Failed to evaluate the FilterValues.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, this should do the trick. You can set the filter expression to an expression - it doesn't just have to be a column value.

```
EXPRESSION (Text)
=Left(Fields!Column.Value,3) 

OPERATOR
[=]

VALUE
=Parameters!Site.Value
```

**EDIT**

You could add a calculated field to the dataset like so:

```
Field Name     Field Source
==========     ============
Site2          =IIF(Fields!Site.Value="C160","C15",LEFT(Fields!Site.Value,3))
```

And Have your Site parameter have the following Available Values:

```
Label          Value
=====          =====
C15            C15
C16            C16
```

Your filter would then look like this:

```
EXPRESSION (Text)
=Fields!Site2.Value

OPERATOR
[=]

VALUE
=Parameters!Site.Value
```

**HOWEVER**
*my two pence worth*
It seems like business rules are driving this requirement. I would strongly recommend AGAINST calculating business rules in report expressions. Business rules change over time and it can be cumbersome to change rdl files. Better to have one central location where rules like this are stored. Lookup tables or UDFs are ideal, or at worst a stored procedure or embedded query will do.

It is much better to put this in the dataset if you have the ability to change it. You then have the ability to annotate the code which creates this grouping to include a reason WHY C160 is thought to be the same as C15.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..The problem i am having is, i have series of values from C150 to C159 and (C160 which i have to include with the first series). Getting 3 lettes of the field will bring C15 and all but i want to add C160 along with the values. That is why i am adding in expression.

Comment: So what i want is, C150 to C159 and C160...Then C161 to C169

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That is very good suggestion. I like it and helped me to get go closer to my solution. Cheers